# How to use tableView propriety in a UITableViewCell class

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

In my swift project I have a tableViewController, with class TableViewController, and one prototype cell, with class TableViewCell.
Now I want to use: tableView.reloadData(), or other function, in the class TableViewCell.
I put a button into the prototype cell, here the code:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   let tableViewController = TableViewController()

    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    tableViewController.tableView.reloadData() // or other function 

}
}
```

by this method the result is: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.
I checked that the class TableViewController is loaded before than the class TableViewCell, so I don't found the problem.
Can you help me to find how this error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't call TableViewController from other class

you need to use [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) or [protocol](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html)

Comment: Thank you In fact I used Notification center and now I'll  try with protocols

Answer (score 1):

Your `actionButton` method is creating a new instance of `TableViewController` each time it's called. It does not refer to the `TableViewController` which (presumably) is presenting the cells.

You can handle this in a few of ways. A `delegate` protocol is the "classic" way to do this, or you could use a Swift closure.

**Delegate method**

In your cell

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func tableViewCellDidTapButton(_ tableViewCell: TableViewCell)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var weak delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.tableViewCellDidTapButton(self)
    }
}
```

In your view controller

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
        let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension class TableViewController: TableViewCellDelegate {
    func tableViewCellDidTapButton(_ tableViewCell: TableViewCell) {
        let indexPath = indexPath(for: tableViewCell)
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Closure method**

In your cell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var didTapButton: Void -> () = { }

    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        didTapButton()
    }
}
```

In your view controller

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
        let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.didTapButton = { 
            // do something with this indexPath
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```